# how to set up a horizontal scrolling Menu?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have been wondering on how to set up a scrolling (Horizontal) Menu. I have seen some tutorials but in Cocos2d and Cocos2d and SpriteKit are completely different things. I am working in swift and have no clue on how to implement this. I saw a GithHub repository which did a scrolling menu tutorial but it was in Objective-C and I know a bit of Objective-C but there was alot of files in the project to convert. Or is it possible to convert the Cocos2d to swift? I was thinking that I may be able to use a UIPageViewController to get my desired effect. If there is anybody out there who knows how to do this.

Thanks!

Here's the Cocos2d Code and the blog post is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130701062139/http://www.givp.org/blog/2010/12/30/scrolling-menus-in-cocos2d).

```
// get screen size
CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
// PAGE 1
////////////////////////////////////////////////
// create a blank layer for page 1
CCLayer *pageOne = [[CCLayer alloc] init];

// create a label for page 1
CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Page 1" fontName:@"Arial    Rounded MT Bold" fontSize:44];
label.position =  ccp( screenSize.width /2 , screenSize.height/2 );

// add label to page 1 layer
[pageOne addChild:label];

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
// PAGE 2
////////////////////////////////////////////////
// create a blank layer for page 2
CCLayer *pageTwo = [[CCLayer alloc] init];

// create a custom font menu for page 2
CCLabelBMFont *tlabel = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"Page 2"  fntFile:@"customfont.fnt"];
CCMenuItemLabel *titem = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:tlabel target:self     selector:@selector(testCallback:)];
CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems: titem, nil];
menu.position = ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2);

// add menu to page 2
[pageTwo addChild:menu];
////////////////////////////////////////////////

// now create the scroller and pass-in the pages (set widthOffset to 0 for fullscreen pages)
 CCScrollLayer *scroller = [[CCScrollLayer alloc] initWithLayers:[NSMutableArray  arrayWithObjects: pageOne,pageTwo,pageThree,nil] widthOffset: 230];

// finally add the scroller to your scene
[self addChild:scroller];
```

[Click for the The GithHub Project](https://www.google.ie/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDQQFjAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fhsilived%2FScrollingMenu&ei=PL3oVMynAYav7Aap7IGgBQ&usg=AFQjCNFxuDRwnVKp9__YKWUDt4FNEj90yw&sig2=n3Ose4zPOxwBHtDSNl9KjQ&bvm=bv.86475890,d.ZGU)

Comment: Add all your menu content as children to one node. Add that node to the view. Use the toucheMoved method to "drag" the menu node left or right and the touchesBegan/Ended methods to handle selections of menu options.

Comment: @sangony I can sort of get where your going with that but how will I move or basically scroll through the scene. I want a simular effect in the game 'Geometry Dash' in their menu's

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What do you mean by "scroll through the scene"? I am not familiar with the game you mentioned. It would help to clarify what it is exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: This is basically what I want to do @sagony - http://youtu.be/4TkrQ5SCnvU?t=2m3s

Comment: Also could I use a page navigation controller for that?